# Install TShark on MacOS X Catalina

Tags: wireshark, tshark, pyshark

I need to install TShark and Dumpcap to be able to use pyshark for a project I am working on. Currently this is the error that I am getting:

pyshark.tshark.tshark.TSharkNotFoundException: TShark not found. Try adding its location to the configuration file. Searched these paths: ['C:\Program Files\Wireshark\dumpcap.exe', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/dumpcap', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/dumpcap', '/usr/local/bin/dumpcap', '/usr/bin/dumpcap', '/bin/dumpcap', '/usr/sbin/dumpcap', '/sbin/dumpcap', '/opt/X11/bin/dumpcap']

I have tried installing tshark via using brew but cant get it with the wireshark package because that requires the --with-qt option which is no longer supported.

I have found dumpcap and tshark executables that come with the desktop version of wireshark but i'm not sure of a good way of linking them in my system without breaking everything. The executables I have found are at /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). You should ask this on [Wireshark's forum](https://ask.wireshark.org) as it is off-topic here.

Comment: I just had a similar issue. Are you trying to access TShark from a virtual environment?